# Change forecolor in Listview depending on value excel vba

Tags: excel, vba

Hope you can help me... I have a displayed data on my listview. The column Headers are:

**ROW ID  CUSTOMER PICKUP DELIVERY LOAD PLACE BAGS AMOUNT STATUS** -*total of 10 columns*

I want the forecolor in my column **STATUS** depends on the value. the value is either **PAID** or **UNPAID**, if **PAID** the color should be green and if **UNPAID**, the color should be red.

I have this code, but it not working for me, somebody will help me? Thank you in advance.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Activate()

Dim C As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim R As Long

ListView1.View = lvwReport
ListView1.HideSelection = False
ListView1.FullRowSelect = True
ListView1.HotTracking = True
ListView1.HoverSelection = False

ListView1.ColumnHeaders.Add Text:="Row", Width:=40

  For C = 1 To 12
    ListView1.ColumnHeaders.Add Text:=Cells(1, C).Text
    ComboBox1.AddItem Cells(1, C).Text
  Next C

**' |In this part of my code is not working|**
Dim Item    As ListItem
Dim counter As Long

For counter = 1 To listView1.ListItems.Count
    Set Item = listView1.ListItems.Item(counter)
    If Item.SubItems(10) = "Paid" Then
        listView1.ListItems.Item(counter).ListSubItems(10).ForeColor = vbGreen
    End If
    If Item.SubItems(10) = "Unpaid" Then
        listView1.ListItems.Item(counter).ListSubItems(10).ForeColor = VBRed


Next counter


End Sub
```

Comment: not 10  , to be 9.  Item.SubItems(10) ~~~>Item.SubItems(9)

Comment: @Dy.Lee I tried it already still not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

listsubitime must be 9, since index numbers start at 0.
In my test, it work well.

[image]

```
Private Sub UserForm_Activate()

Dim C As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim R As Long
Dim li As ListItem

ListView1.View = lvwReport
ListView1.HideSelection = False
ListView1.FullRowSelect = True
ListView1.HotTracking = True
ListView1.HoverSelection = False

ListView1.ColumnHeaders.Add Text:="Row", Width:=40

  For C = 1 To 12
    ListView1.ColumnHeaders.Add Text:=Cells(1, C).Text
    ComboBox1.AddItem Cells(1, C).Text
  Next C
Dim vDB
vDB = Range("a1").CurrentRegion
For i = 2 To UBound(vDB, 1)
    Set li = ListView1.ListItems.Add
    For j = 1 To UBound(vDB, 2)
    With li
        .Text = i
        .ListSubItems.Add , , vDB(i, j)
    End With
    Next j
Next i
'**' |In this part of my code is not working|**
Dim Item    As ListItem
Dim counter As Long

For counter = 1 To ListView1.ListItems.Count
    Set Item = ListView1.ListItems.Item(counter)
    If Item.SubItems(9) = "Paid" Then
        ListView1.ListItems.Item(counter).ListSubItems(9).ForeColor = vbGreen
    End If
    If Item.SubItems(9) = "Unpaid" Then
        ListView1.ListItems.Item(counter).ListSubItems(9).ForeColor = vbRed
    End If

Next counter


End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!. So much appreciated!